# Generate war in parent target directory using maven

Tags: maven, maven-war-plugin

I have a multi-module project as follows:

parent-project:

```
---> base-project
---> sub-web-project
```

base-project will generate a jar file which sub-web-project depends on, sub-web-project will generate a war file located in the sub-web-project's target directory, how can I generate sub-web-project's war file in parent-project's target directory?

Comment: Why would you like to do this? What is the reason?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `outputDirectory` along with relative path to the parent pom (`../target`): https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html#outputDirectory